# Simple way of comparing two Lists in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm, comparison

I'm looking for a simplified way to compare Lists in C#. Currently what I'm doing is the following:
1. Initiate original list
2. Initiate updated list
3. Manually compare using Union, Except, etc., to get the differences.

The application in question is a Windows Phone 8.1 app, implemented using MVVM. I'm reading files on the phone storage, parsing the StorageFiles into custom classes, and then doing the comparison. Given that I can't do it directly, so far I did it manually, which is VERY slow.

What I'm looking for is:

- Get the new items (quite easy)
- Get the updated items (hard!)

It would be so great if there was a basic CRUD environment built into Lists....

Any way, the question is still the same - is there an easy/simple way of doing what I am, or should I just stick with the working solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "comparing"? Comparing corresponding idnexes? Comparing existance of a reference? Show the code.

Comment: Comparing the contents of the list, basically determining the differences between the original and the new one (so, in layman's terms, pointing out the new items, changed items, deleted items, and unchanged items).

Comment: Define "pointing out the new items, changed items, deleted items, and unchanged items". Do you want to compare the references?

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from my description. Yes, I wish to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As for updated implement a TimeStamp property that is updated when any property is changed.
Then you can just compare the TimeSpamp property.

Comment: Okay after running some tests, it is clear that apparently the creation of the two separate lists result in creating different references. So the time stamp method won't work, as the two list contain different references, while the objects themselves can be the same.

Comment: So you comparing two references to the same object for differences.  Timesstamp works - it will be the same for two references to the same object as will every property.

Comment: No. As I said, the two lists contain different references, different objects. What I do is the following: 1. Get list of files 2. Create custom objects out of list of files (whereas the objects have a reference to said file, given I'm working on WP8.1, it's a StorageFile) 3. Add custom object to list 4. Compare lists.

Comment: And as the custom object is later on filled with information about the file (e.g. size, date of creation, other metadata), the objects are separate. The best solution I can think of would be using a custom implementation of the ObservableCollection<T> class, where I override the Compare function to go element by element and check for differences manually, but it's a damn tedious work, and I was hoping for a simpler solution in existence.

Comment: It is messy, but that's the only solution I found so far for populating a library of files with custom relations (it is a music library - music files are parsed into Song objects, Artist and Album classes are created, etc. I'm comparing two lists of Songs: the currently used one, and the to-be-loaded one)